# Unexpected result using SELECT ... WHERE id = 0 on VARCHAR id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm using MySQL 8 with InnoDB with a node server with mysql2 driver.

My table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
      id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
      name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      ...
      PRIMARY KEY (id) 
     )
```

I use no auto increment and as VARCHAR ids, I use time based UUIDs.

If I now do my SELECT query:

```
SELECT * FROM users where id = 'some valid id';
```

I get my expected result.

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM users where id = '0';
```

I get nothing, because no id in my table has the value '0'.

BUT, if i do:

```
SELECT * FROM users where id = 0;
```

I get the last inserted row, which has, of course, a valid VARCHAR id different from 0.

This behavior occured on my node server by accident, because JS sometimes interpretes undefined as 0 in http querys.
In consequence I can easyly avoid inserting 0 in my querys (what I do now), but I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: Can you show an example of such an ID returned by the query for the third case `where id = 0;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` is `varchar()`, so this comparison:

```
WHERE id = 0
```

requires type conversion.

According to the conversion rules in SQL, the `id` is turned into a string.  Now, in many databases, you would get an error if any values of `id` could not be converted into numbers.

However, MySQL supports implicit conversion *with no errors*. (You can read about such conversion in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).)   This converts all leading digits to a number -- ignoring the rest.   If there are no leading digits, then the value is zero.  So, all these are true in MySQL:

- `'a' = 0`
- `'0a' = 0'`
- `'anything but 0!' = 0`

There are two morals to this story.

1. If you really want `id` to be a number, then use a number data type (`int`, `bigint`, `decimal`).
2. Don't mix types in comparisons.